# Excel formula exceeds 8000 characters limit

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that is 8433 characters, and it appears the limit for excel is 8192. It's a lengthy "if" statement, with 70+ conditions. Is there a more efficient way to evaluate the criteria in order to get less characters in the formula below?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AD3),"",IF(
SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stock",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"DRIP",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stock",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stock",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"ETF",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"DRIP",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"ETF",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"ETF",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Commodity",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"DRIP",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Commodity",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Commodity",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Managed Fund",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"DRIP",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Managed Fund",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Managed Fund",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"REIT",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"DRIP",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"REIT",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"REIT",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)

-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stock",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stock",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"ETF",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"ETF",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Commodity",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Commodity",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Managed Fund",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Managed Fund",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"REIT",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"REIT",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)

+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Crypto",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Crypto Interest",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Crypto",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Crypto",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Crypto",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Crypto",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)

+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stablecoin",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Crypto Interest",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stablecoin",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stablecoin",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stablecoin",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stablecoin",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$M$3:$M,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$B$3:$B,AD3)=0,"Sold All",

SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stock",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"DRIP",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stock",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stock",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"ETF",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"DRIP",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"ETF",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"ETF",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Commodity",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"DRIP",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Commodity",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Commodity",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Managed Fund",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"DRIP",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Managed Fund",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Managed Fund",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"REIT",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"DRIP",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"REIT",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"REIT",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)

-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stock",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stock",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"ETF",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"ETF",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Commodity",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Commodity",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Managed Fund",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Managed Fund",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"REIT",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"REIT",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)

+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Crypto",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Crypto Interest",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Crypto",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Crypto",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Crypto",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Crypto",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)

+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stablecoin",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Crypto Interest",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stablecoin",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
+SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Deposit",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stablecoin",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Transfer Send",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stablecoin",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Sell",Transactions!$F$3:$F,"Stablecoin",Transactions!$D$3:$D,AD3)
-SUMIFS(Transactions!$M$3:$M,Transactions!$H$3:$H,"Buy",Transactions!$B$3:$B,AD3)))
```

I tried to save the workbook in excel binary workbook format, but macros don't work

Comment: If a formula is that long, it's probably the wrong formula. Can you tell us what it`s supposed to do? Maybe provide sample data and expected outcome too

Comment: This is not Excel but google, they're not the same

Comment: In Excel you could implement `LET` not sure if sheets has that.

Comment: You can implement a user `LAMBDA` function for all the `SUMIFS` calls with a parameter as input that takes different values, such as: Buy, Sell, etc..

Comment: It's supposed to calculate the remaining quantity in "Sheet1" cell C3 from the "Transactions" sheet inputs by subtracting the sells and outflows form the buys and inflows. It works perfectly in google sheets because gs has no character limit. Here is the sample data  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LuguuynFTxw6ZFbAsIIEElYSPKtyvrRFIMqan5HMMYU/edit#gid=0

Comment: Create a conditions table and then do a lookup instead of a lengthy nested IF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `LET()` is optimal, it does make an assumption about your version of Excel that you haven't indicated can be made - an alternative approach valid in legacy Excel is to use named ranges for the 4 different ranges duplicated (69 times) throughout your formula, e.g.
[image: screenshot illustrating use of range names to shorten formula]
(in using the shorter named ranges illustrated the length of the formula has been more than halved)

A more pragmatic approach might be to familiarise yourself with [array constants](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-constant), e.g. the summation of the first 15 `SUMIFS()` functions can also be achieved by this more succinct [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula):

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Transactions!$I$3:$I10000,Transactions!$H$3:$H10000,{"Buy";"Drip";"Transfer Deposit"},Transactions!$F$3:$F10000,{"Stock","ETF","Commodity","Managed Fund","REIT"},Transactions!$D$3:$D10000,AD3))
```

(I've made the assumption in both cases that the last row of your data is 10,000 - you should adjust this appropriate to your context, since full-column references should be avoided in Excel)